# Check if Kinect Camera is still available (OpenNI 1.5.4)

Tags: kinect, openni

I try to detect if camera is still available so that my code won't crash if user unplug camera.
I also know that OpenNI version 2 supports the connection/disconnection events. But I am using OpenNi 1.5.4, and for some reasons, I can't upgrade to version 2.
So, is there anyway to implement this kind of functionality on version 1.5.4

Thanks

Comment: I've found the answer. There is an API in XnUSB (xnUSBSetCallbackHandler) that helps me do this :)